# How to use Laravel orderByRaw with condition

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a query like following and wants to set all Customer with building areas < 500 building_areas on end of my list.

My not working query:

```
    $Customers = Customer::query()->orderBy('id','DESC')
                                  ->orderByRaw('(building_areas < 500)','DESC');
```

How to use Laravels orderByRaw in this case?

Comment: sounds a lot more like you want to ``->where('building_areas', '<', 500);``

Comment: Sorry, no. I want all items but set building_areas < 500 at the end of this list.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution if anybody wants to know:

```
    $Customers = Customer::query()->orderByRaw('building_areas >= 500')
                                  ->orderBy('id','DESC');
```